# Automatically add incoming .ics calendar invites to my iCloud calendar

Tags: mail.app, calendar, automation, ical

Is there a way for Mail on my Mac to automatically add .ics calendar invites to my iCloud calendar? I am used to Outlook automatically showing calendar invites as tentative in my calendar, but with Apple tools I need to explicitly click on the .ics file to have it show up in my calendar. Embarrassingly, I've already missed a couple meetings because of this - and really want to see all my invites in my calendar automatically. I'm desperate for a solution and using 3rd party software or scripting is fine if it solves the problem!

*NOTE: there is a very old solution to the problem here, but the option no longer exists (I am using Mail version 15.0):
[Automating .ics import from Mail to iCal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6630/automating-ics-import-from-mail-to-ical)*

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? I am also interested

Comment: Nope, still a mystery.